# What are some tools to convert Java programs into sequence diagrams?

Tags: java, modeling, sequence-diagram

What are some tools to convert Java programs into sequence diagrams?

Comment: Duplicate of [Sequence Diagram Reverse Engineering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87137/sequence-diagram-reverse-engineering)

Answer (score 1):

The [Netbeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/) has [reverse engineering](http://blogs.oracle.com/JavaFundamentals/entry/generating_uml_from_the_netbeans) (fast-forward to the last screenshot in the blog).

Comment: It did, in 2007. Unfortunately, they just took it out in the later versions :/

Answer (score 0):

I believe Enterprise Architect supports Java.

http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/

I've used it for C#.NET and it reverse engineers all your classes / methods / interfaces etc and makes it easy to create sequence diagrams. It is also possible to get a sequence diagram out of a debug session, but I haven't tried that yet!

Answer (score 0):

eclipse can be upgraded with [OMONDO](http://www.ejb3.org/). Which is not free, but they had a free version some years ago and that on was capable of re-engineering Java code to sequence diagrams.

[Here is another big list of UML tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools).

Answer (score 0):

[Poseidon for UML](http://www.gentleware.com/)